# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero в функции Holt пакета statsmodels

Tags: python, статистика

Есть лист:

```
sample = [0.67, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.25]
```

Я хочу сделать предсказания для этого списка на основе модели Хольта-Винтерса

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import Holt

fit1 = Holt(np.asarray(sample), exponential=True).fit(smoothing_level = 0.4,
                                                      smoothing_slope = 0.4)
prediction = fit1.forecast(5)
```

Что возвращает мне ошибку

[image: Division by zero]

Проблемы возникают в случаях, когда длина исходного списка равна 7. 
Кто-нибудь знает, почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Comment: Какая у вас версия `statsmodels`? В последней версии (0.8.0) класс `Holt` отсутствует, как и файл `statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py`

Comment: @MaxU: [`statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/7cbaa2e9c8b996696bdcba08fc12fcf1b5253c49/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py#L733-L735)

Comment: @MaxU я забрал библиотеку из репозитория на гитхабе. В версии же библиотеки, которую можно установить через pip, например, такого модуля действительно нет. 

Смотрел исходники и просто не могу понять, что это за манипуляции, при которых происходит деление на ноль при len(sample)==7. Этого нет в обычной модели Хольта-Винтерса. Может, у кого-то есть идеи, как это пофиксить?

Comment: @jfs, вопрос в том, почему так происходит и что с этим делать - именно его я и задал.

Comment: @Nick_Y, я думаю лучше всего открыть ["issue"](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues) и указать там ваш воспроизводимый пример. Разработчики похоже забыли про "numerical stability"... В таких случаях в знаменателе добавляют `epsilon` (скажем 1e-8)

Comment: @MaxU, да, так и сделаю, пожалуй.
Спасибо